# Delphi, TParameter Properties for datetime and boolean

Tags: delphi, parameters, delphi-xe4

Delphi XE4 Enterprise

I have a query which calls a stored procedure that has 2 parameters:

- `AccessionDate` which is a datetime
- `IncludeHistory` which is a boolean

When I click on the `Parameters` dropdown in the Object Inspector for the query it has the following values:

```
IncludeHistory, boolean:
------------------------
NumericScale 0
Precision 0
Size -1

AccessionDate, datetime
------------------------    
NumericScale 0
Precision 0
Size -1
```

What should the values be for the `NumericScale`, `Precision` and `Size` ?

Comment: Maybe you could give more details like the kind of the dataset and the server you are using? It would help us to help you.

Comment: Aren't that the values indicating "We have defaults, you don't need to specify anything"? Does your code have problems?

Comment: You can reduce your question to your `AccessionDate` parameter and `NumericScale` and `Precision` properties because the [`Size`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TParameter.Size) propery is only for string types and your `IncludeHistory` parameter is of `ftBoolean` data type which doesn't need any of the mentioned properties configured.